# Using Eigen SparseLU results in Assertion failed error

Tags: c++, eigen

I am running into the following error while using Eigen::SparseLU to solve for x in Ax=b where b is a vector.

"Assertion failed: m_factorizationIsOk && "The matrix should be factorized first", file eigen\src\sparselu\sparselu.h, line 220"

The same formulation works for multiple other matrices. Trying to understand what could be the issue with this specific matrix that results in this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you factorize your matrix first? (Before calling `solve()`). Please provide a [mre]!

Comment: Thankyou. I do call compute() before solve(). Also the problem seems to been caused by a different issue in my model. I have resolved it. Again thank you for the quick response

Comment: Not sure this was the problem here but for future readers: Before using a factorized matrix to solve a system, you must check that factorization was successful, by checking `solver.info() == Eigen::Success`